# Syslog-ng prepends <[0-9]+> to my messages

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

I'm writing some parsing logic for syslog-ng messages and am noticing that for many of the commands syslog-ng prepends a `<[0-9]+>` string to most of my messages.

Here is an example from me running `sudo`:

```
<85>Aug  2 09:42:09 sholsapp-ld sudo: sholsapp : TTY=pts/28 ; PWD=/home/sholsapp ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/ls
```

What is the meaning/significance of the `<85>`?

Comment: as Clayton answered, thats the priority+facility. But that shouldn't be showing up. What does your config for that (file) destination look like? You're not using a custom template or anything are you?

Comment: No, just the config file that redhat linux provided when I did `yum install syslog-ng`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the PRI. It is an 8bit number that indicates the severity and facility.
More information is available [HERE](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/collateral/tk869/tk769/white_paper_c11-557812.html#wp9000313)